# jquery .each() incorrectly updating object

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, basically, an object in an object in an object.

```
alertQ = {
    0: {
        French: {
            start: "1am",
            duration: "1hr",
            status: "queued"
        }
    },
    1: {
        Italian: {
            start: "2am",
            duration: "2hr",
            status: "queued"
        }
    },
    2: {
        // ...etc...
    }
};

function sendTrades(){
    var trades = $J("#queue_listbox input:checked");
    $J.each(trades, function(key, val){ //iterate thru any selected option
        var id = val.value; //checkbox value contains object "id"
        $J.each(alertQ[id], function(key, val){
            Dbug(key);
            alertQ[id][key].status = "active";
            //val.status = "active"; //this was also tried with same result
        });
    });
    drawTrades(); //utility function. read only. creates the <input> checkbox elements for display, and is fired before this function to initialize the list
}
```

I can correctly navigate to the innermost object and read the variables from there.
The whole `alertQ` object is constructed with jQuery .each() loops in basically the same way `sendTrades()` is attempting to modify it.
It builds perfectly & is accessible from console.
`sendTrades()` is fired upon a button click.
The problem arises when I select one from a list greater than 1, let's assume I've selected **French**:
`Dbug(key);` fires correctly, and names **French** only. *Dbug simply passes data to `console.log()`*
ALL `status` values are changed to `"active"` << should not happen

I have tried selecting all options and console logging indicates correctly all names, and all `status` are changed to `"active"` as it should.
But why does it change them all when it should only change the selected ones as mentioned above?

sample HTML below

```
<input value="0" type="checkbox">French
<input value="1" type="checkbox">Italian
<input value="2" type="checkbox">...etc...
```

If need be, the 3rd-nested object could be merged into the 2nd-nested object.

Comment: This is almost unreadable. We didn't develop that project with you so I'm not certainly sure what you are talking about. are you claiming that $.each is not working? can you please attach a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1eyd1crk/ but here is the curious thing: it works as intended in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not like you are setting all to active but in your tests,  you'r are not resetting alertQ object again. So first time you select all and all status are set to "active", in second test, you only check one box and it's setting that one to active but previous ones are already set to active.

Here is example: http://jsbin.com/vonumiqi/1/

```
//You need to reset the non active to queued or other status you want.

var tradesUnChecked = $("#check1 :not('input:checked')");
$.each(tradesUnChecked, function(key, val){ //iterate thru any selected option
    var id = val.value; //checkbox value contains object "id"
     console.log(alertQ[id]);
    $.each(alertQ[id], function(key, val){

        console.log(key);
        alertQ[id][key].status = "queued";
        //val.status = "active"; //this was also tried with same result
    });
});
```

Comment: i have included a jsfiddle showing example, and here is the kicker -- on there, it works.

Comment: The code you shown in fiddle above is different than what it's in question. In fiddle example you are already checking the status property of object before setting it to active and then you remake the input list.The code in fiddle is correct and so it's working.

Comment: How is it different than from in my question? Infact, I pasted the code direct from my project

Comment: What I mean to say to is processTradeObj(obj) function in fiddle, is making the list again with status check. Also when setting status in sendTrades() function, you can add the same check(just to be sure that you are reading from queue_listbox). Can not see anything wrong in your code, it might be something else interfering.

Comment: I must have something else interfering - I have another object that is built from a large selection of `<input>`s that eventually is used to create `alertQ` and its contents are set and never updated, yet all of the `status` variables are being changed in there as well.  (I am going to sleep on it and try fix it tomorrow, thanks for help so far guys.)

Comment: Setting debug point in javascript console (F12) will guide you to narrow it down. You can see when sendTrades is called , which values your received in trades variable and which alertQ objects are set to active, in that function. I believe it's just a small overlooked mistake somewhere, take a break and you will find it.